# How do I make a button and input box transition at the same time?

Tags: css, http

I've got a `search box` which `transitions` and gets bigger when clicked on, and there is a `button` beside it. My problem is that the `input box` moves softly but the `button` stays in place and then `teleports` to its position once the `transition` is over. How can I trigger a `transition` on the button once the input box is clicked?

```
 .searchbox {
      width: 150px;
      height: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: white;
      background-position: 2px 2px; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 45px;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      margin-top:10px;

    }

.searchbox:focus {
      width: 100%;
    }


.searchbt {
      float: left;
      width: 15px;
      height: 4px;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #2196F3;
      color: white;
      font-size: 17px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border:none;
      margin-top:10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:1;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      border-right:none;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
.searchbt:focus {
      width=100%;
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit: I temporarily fixed it by moving the button to the other side (The one which doesn't move)

Comment: You have a typo in your css: `width=100%;` and you forgot to share your HTML.

Comment: HTML? It would help.